# how can i stop users from dragging a page horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has a horizontal scroll feature, and when a button is pressed the DIV containing the scrolling content animates to the left.

The width of that element is 18000px, so it has a horizontal scrollbar that I disabled.

However I could still drag my page left and right and I would like to stop users doing that. Is there a css solution to my problem? Thanks for your time

Comment: im asking how to stop people dragging the page left and right with their mouse

Comment: And there's an answer to your exact question on that thread.

Comment: As the answers in that question state; cancel events that could lead to a scroll, before the scroll event, and implement a "snap to default" if a scroll somehow gets through the net.

Comment: will they be able to scroll vertically with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose using `overflow:hidden` on the DIV and use javascript to control the `margin-left` to shift left and right will do the job

Edit Add example:

```
<!-- The "Frame" -->
<div class="container" style="width:1024px;overflow:hidden">
  <div class="very-long-div" style="width:18000px">
     Your awesome content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, hide the horizontal scrollbar by doing `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`.

Comment: I can still drag by holding the left mouse key down and dragging right