# DISABLING horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I made a one-page website with parallax scrolling, and background images of 1920x1080px.

I added `overflow-x: hidden;` in the body (in the stylesheet). The horizontal scrollbar dissapeard, wich is good, but users can still scroll horizontaly with their middle mouse button. I don't want that and don't know how to disable it. I googled for like 1-1.5 hours, but the only thing I found was the `overflow-x: hidden;` wich does not DISABLE the scrolling.

If anyone knows a solution for this problem, please tell me.

Thank you,

Jordi B.

Comment: I would rather mark your question as a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640274/how-can-i-stop-users-from-dragging-a-page-horizontally, but it is still a duplicate.

Comment: body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

Its because some divisions are extending beyond the page. Check the divisions by giving them a background color. And look for the one extended more.

Comment: how can i know what division over extends, they are all 1920 wide, and my laptop's screen is 1366, it is for every screen different, how would I make it so the division fit the screen perfectly, maybe that is a solution

Comment: try opening the page in firefox and press your right arrow button. The page may move to right.

Comment: does it need to be in firefox? or can i try it in chrome to? i can't move horizontaly with my arrow keys in chrome

Comment: that's what I thought. It happened to me. Try in firefox

Comment: ok i'l install firefox and try it, hang in there :) thank you for your help

Comment: yup, i can move to the right with my arrows in mozilla firefox

Comment: what do i need to do to prevent that? the users of the side must be unable to scroll horizontaly

Comment: find what causes the problem. or try setting the width of the division like 95% something like that.